# Jquery: Select full href with a 'contains' method

Tags: jquery, select, attributes, href, parents

Is it possible using jQuery to select one full link which href contains another variable?

My code is:

```
var element1 = $(".not-viewed").parents('li').attr("id");

var element2 = $(".videoTitle").attr("href");
```

Where i need to select a full link that contains 'element1',because there several videos in the page.In my code select the first on the page,but i need the specific with id..
Example..[In this example the code that i need is: **1581889025**]

```
    <li class="videoContainer vidLink" id="1581889025">
    <a href="site.com../view/1581889025:49_3eA8F7sPr5FQGZcl2yzx3dz5Y_XwP">
    <span class="HOVER"></span>
    <div class="videoX"><img id="clThumb_1581889025" src="PREVIEW.jpg">
    </div>  </a>
    <a class="videoTitle" href="site.com../view/1581889025:49_3eA8F7sPr5FQGZcl2yzx3dz5Y_XwP">Title of Video</a>
<span class='not-viewed'></span>
<div class="tooltip-footer"></div>
</li>
```

Thanks in advance.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [attribute-contains selector (`*=`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), like this:

```
var id = $(".not-viewed").parents('li').attr("id");
var href = $(".videoTitle[href*='" + id + "']").attr("href");
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QSfsb/), you may also want `$(".videoTitle[href*='/" + id + ":']")` to narrow it down to `/1581889025:` matches, in case there was a `15818890250` for example.

Comment: var href = $("a.videoTitle[href*='" + id + "']").attr("href"); - You should add "a" in the selector as other markup may also contain videoTitle class. (Although it doesn't matter much but I think it will be a bit faster as well.)

Comment: @Vikash - It depends on the browser we to which is faster :) But yes that's a valid selector as well, my point was more to demonstrate the attribute portion while only clarifying, not changing the rest :)

Comment: Thanks to all,work all perfectly :-)                                 I add all your names in my project ;-)     Very thanks..

Comment: @Luca - Welcome :) be sure to accept answers if they resolve your question!